# How to store a JavaScript variable into a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the following example of code I want to store the JavaScript variable `val` into a PHP variable `$ff`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#type").change(function() {
       var val = $(this).val();
       alert(val);
       <?php $ff = "Greenway"; ?>
   });

  });
</script>
```

The var `val` stores the name of shops, e.g. "GreenWay", "Tropin". I want to store this data in a PHP variable. I tried doing `<?php $ff = $_GET['val']; ?>` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it because PHP is server side language and javascript client side.

It means PHP is executed in a first time, the result (html + css + js) is sent to the client. Then when the client receive it, JS can be executed.

If you want JS to send a variable to the server (PHP), you can use AJAX : [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: How should I do it? Do you have any example?

Comment: The documentation I have linked has some example. Its important to learn how to use documentation. Try first by yourself then if you have some problems come back.

Comment: take a look above duplicate question link